# How login form works in ror?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am trying to learn Ruby on Rails. I have followed youtube tutorial to create simple authentication in ruby. Everything is working fine but I cant understand it.

I have routes

```
resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

get 'signup', to: 'users#new', as: 'signup'
get 'login', to: 'sessions#new', as: 'login'
get 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'logout'
```

I have controllers for sessions and users

sessions_controller

```
def new
end

def create
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Logged in !'
  else
    render :new
  end
end

def destroy
  session[:user_id] = nil
  redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Logged out!'
end
```

and my views/sessions/new.html.erb

```
<h1>Log In</h1>
<%= form_tag sessions_path do %>
<div class="field">
<%= label_tag :email %><br>
<%= text_field_tag :email %>
</div>
 <div class="field">
   <%= label_tag :password %><br>
<%= password_field_tag :password %>
</div>
 <div class="actions">
  <%= submit_tag "Log In" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

I want to understand how my login form works . I understand that when i go to /login it will request action from session controller and method new, but how it knows when i type my email and password and press submit what to do next ?  In php there is  . How it works in ruby ?

Comment: `In php there is .` could you elaborate please? ^^

Comment: Sorry i wanted to paste : in php there is <form action="/sessions" method="post">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a pretty broad question, but I will try to explain some of the rails-magic you probably want to know.

First, you should take a closer look at [the viewhelper docs, especially form_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag). It will create a form html tag with the sessions_path as first argument and the do-block as the second.
`sessions_path` is a view helper, provided by rails because you used

```
resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
```

in your routes. It returns a string that should look like this `"/sessions"`. You should take a look at [this guide to understand rails routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) better.

```
<%= form_tag sessions_path do %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

is the same as

```
<form action="/sessions" method="post">
  ...
</form>
```

So, the submit is nothing more than a regular html form submit to "/sessions". Rails will map a post request to "/sessions" to the SessionsController#create method, where we authenticate the user by email and password and set the id in the session cookie

```
if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
  session[:user_id] = user.id
  # ...
```

Comment: Only thing i do not understand is how does it know that it needs to use SessionsController#create method and not some other method ?

Comment: Ok if i type rake routes i can see there is /sessions path mapped to sessions#create

Comment: Take some time to read this, and you'll understand how it knows what controller and action to load: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Thanks @Chris Peters , Will do

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Ninigi's good answer I just wanted to add that ...

resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

will generate routes which you can view by using `rake routes` in the terminal.

Also form_tag etc are just view helpers that will generate html, simply use inspect element in your browser to see what it has done.

I would have added this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 2):

A very good starting point for understanding this will be the book Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl. Its available free to read online.

See chapter 7 onwards for login/signup etc.

The step by step explanations are very useful.

The link : https://www.railstutorial.org/book

and welcome to RoR